# TypeScript doesn't see the type check in a switch statement

Tags: typescript

Problem:

I'm using a simple switch statement to check whether our property is not undefined, so we could implement an addition.

But somehow TS Compiler doesn't take into account my type check implemented by the switch statement, so it's sending me this error - "'markObj.BMI' is possibly 'undefined'.", however the same type check written using an if/else statement works perfectly...

Code:

```
interface Person {
  fullName: string;
  mass: number;
  height: number;
  BMI: number | undefined;

  calcBMI: () => number;
}

const markObj: Person = {
  fullName: "Mark Miller",
  mass: 78,
  height: 1.69,
  BMI: undefined,

  calcBMI: function (): number {
    const BMI: number = this.mass / this.height ** 2;

    this.BMI = BMI;
    return this.BMI;
  },
};

if (markObj.BMI !== undefined) {
  console.log(markObj.BMI + 3);
}

switch (true) {
  case markObj.BMI !== undefined:
    console.log(markObj.BMI + 3);
}
```

So how do I make this switch statement work without this pesky error just as it works with the if/else statement ?

Comment: What you want is currently impossible as per [ms/TS#8934](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8934) and [ms/TS#37178](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37178); it's just not a pattern used commonly enough for it to be worth the extra processing time to check for it.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, I guess the second provided link explains my situation. Thank you! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't currently do any [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) in a `switch (true) { ⋯ }` block.  A request to support such narrowing, filed at [microsoft/TypeScript#8934](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8934), was declined [because](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8934#issuecomment-253643139)

> In order to keep things simple, narrowing only supports a few common syntactic forms. We do expand this list from time to time, but I don't think the `switch (true)` pattern is common enough to make it on the list.

A susbsequent similar request at [microsoft/37178](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37178) remains open and marked as "awaiting more feedback", meaning that they'd want to see more demand from the community before even thinking of implementing it.  You *might* want to go there, describe your use case, and why the refactoring to `if`/`else` statements isn't acceptable, but pragmatically speaking it probably wouldn't have much of an effect.  I'd say that it's unlikely that this will be implemented anytime soon, for a similar reason to what was mentioned in the prior issue: there is a complexity and performance cost to [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis), so any expansion of that analysis would need to pay for itself.  A coding pattern needs to be quite common indeed in order for it to be worthwhile for the compiler to check for it.

So until and unless this is implemented, what you want is impossible, and if you want to see narrowing here you should refactor to the equivalent `if`/`else` statements.